# Mvn test executes all tests correctly however mvn DTest gives error

Tags: java, maven, testing

I have a test case:

```
import org.graph.*;
import org.junit.*;

public class TestCase_1
{
    @Test
    public void test_1() {
      System.out.println("Hello World");
      new A().bat();
    }
}
```

When I run mvn test the test runs perfectly.

However, when I execute

```
mvn -Dtest=TestCase_1 test_1
```

I get the following error:

```
Unknown lifecycle phase "test_1". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy.
```

Does anyone have any idea how to resolve this. I have tried specifying lifecycle goals but it still results in the same error.

Comment: test_1 is not a valid lifecycle: Have a look at https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). - Read the mvn documentation. anything which is not preceded by an dashed option is treated as a lifecycle phase which has to exist.

Comment: Looks like you want `mvn -Dtest=TestCase_1#test_1`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to execute your test as below commands:

All test case:

```
mvn test
```

Specify test case:

```
mvn -Dtest=TestCase_1 test
```

if you have the library 'maven-surefire-plugin' which version is 2.7.3 or later.
you can specify the specific method

```
mvn -Dtest=TestCase_1#test_1 test
```

Please try them.